# Error while installing Rhythmbox Mozilla Plugin

Tags: 18.04, rhythmbox, mozilla

I am trying to install Rhythmbox Mozilla PLugin via Synaptic. But I am getting the following error:

```
rhythmbox-mozilla:
  Depends: rhythmbox (=3.4.2-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

The command:

```
apt-cache policy rhythmbox-mozilla
```

gives the prompt:

```
rhythmbox-mozilla:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.4.2-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04
  Version table:
     3.4.2-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: There is [no official package for 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=rhythmbox-mozilla&searchon=names). Please add output of `apt-cache policy rhythmbox-mozilla` to the question.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 0):

We have two problems here:

1. [`ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps` PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/apps?field.series_filter=bionic) does not respect current version of `rhythmbox` package from official repository (so it won't install);
2. Even if we install `rhythmbox-mozilla` package with some hacks, it will not work with modern Firefox 53+ Quantum (see quote from latest package [Changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/3.4.2-4ubuntu1)):

   > **rhythmbox 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 source package in Ubuntu**
   >   **Changelog**
   >
   > rhythmbox (3.4.2-4ubuntu1) bionic; urgency=medium
   >   ...
   >   * Stop building rhythmbox-plugin-mozilla since it won't work in Firefox 53+

---

But if you need to play video in your browser, then you can install [Mozilla SeaMonkey all-in-one internet application suite](https://www.seamonkey-project.org/) and use it with VLC-plugin:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla.list
deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main
EOF

sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 2667CA5C
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-vlc seamonkey-mozilla-build
```

I view RTSP streams this way on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.